# Google Sheets copy function among merged cells

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to create a reference to another tab in my sheet, but am having trouble copying (dragging) the function in "Print" tab downwards. Because I am using merged cells in Print tab, the function skips 8 rows every time. What I want to achieve is that it will reference every next cell as it would normally do if there were no merged cells.

[Link to Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1chLwIK7iJqzJInd-uSU2Wl8R5gK-kgNxElLL8e_Z8B4/edit?usp=sharing)

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how this works and how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

that's not gonna work as you wish, but you can use ArrayFormula. merge your cells in 2's and 8's and then use this formula in A2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({'QR Generator'!A2; 'QR Generator'!A2; 
 IFNA(IF((MOD(ROW(A1:A), 10)=0)+(MOD(ROW(A1:A)+1, 10)=0), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDIRECT("QR Generator!A3:A"&
 COUNTA('QR Generator'!A3:A)+2)&"×", 10)), "×")), 
 IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=540x540&cht=qr&chl="&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(INDIRECT("QR Generator!A2:A"&
 COUNTA('QR Generator'!A2:A)+1)&"×", 10)), "×")))))}, ROWS(A2:A), 1))
```

[image: 0]